# Center Flexislider Images in NON-Responsive website

Tags: css

I need the slider's images always centered in a non-responsive websites
[ignitetechnology](http://www.ignitetechnology.co.uk/ignite_hospitality_modx/)
...at the moment when resizing the window the images are cutted from the right....I don't know if is possible...
does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
#slider img {
width:100%; height: auto;
 }
```

and also set slider width in % example

```
#slider {
width:100%; 
}
```